# Bibtex/natbib: how can you print same bibliography twice?

Tags: natbib, subdividing, multibib

I want to compile my document with in the end a list of all my cited sources: 'references', but also a list of 'recommended readings', so a re-print of the same bibliography that outputs ALL sources and not solely the ones I've cited.

Is this possible? I am using xetex, bibtex icm natbib

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{articles}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that combines `natbib` and [`multibib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multibib).

Note: Unless you use a tool like `latexmk`, you have to compile the following MWE using

```
latex <mydoc>
bibtex <mydoc>
bibtex rec
latex <mydoc>
latex <mydoc>
```

as specified in section 2 of the `multibib` documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{rec}{Recommended readings}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01}.

\nociterec{*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mybib}

\bibliographystylerec{plainnat}
\bibliographyrec{mybib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuses, marked this early as an answer. Problem is that It doesn't generate the 'recommended reading part'. Is this due to this error? `No file rec.bbl`

Comment: @Mixhael I updated my answer.

Comment: Tnx. It does work. However, now I run into this problem again: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/package-natbib-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations/54482#54482 and the solution proposed on that question does not work anymore. Somehow there is a conflict between those too?

Comment: @Mixhael When deleting the auxiliary files, look out for files called  `rec.<whatever>` and delete those also.

Comment: Hm, not sure if I'm doing it correctly: 1) deleted all files, except my .tex and .bib file. Ran xelatex latexfile, then bibtex bibtexlibrary, then bibtex rec, then xelatex latexfile and finally xelatex latexfile. Resulting in the same error: `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. (natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.`. Re-running the process (after removing all the .bbl and .aux files) results in the same

Comment: @Mixhael The first BibTeX run should be bibtex latexfile.

Comment: excuses, that's actually what I do/did

Comment: @Mixhael Does this happen also if you compile my MWE as-is? If not, the problem might be in your `.bib` file.

Comment: Hm, your version works perfectly...

Comment: Would the use of latexmk solve this issue?

Comment: @Mixhael If my example works for you, probably not. Try with parts of your `.bib` file -- there may be a single entry that causes the problem.

Comment: Tnx alot. Did some debugging and all works fine now :)