# Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: bibtex, errors, natbib

I have a basic tex file and a bibliography which is exported from Mendeley

However, when I want to cite in the author-year style, I get the error:

`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
(natbib) Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.`

Any clue what's wrong?

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{articles}

\end{document}
```

A snippet of my .bib library:

```
@article{shortcode,
author = {Lastname, Firstname},
file = {:/path/to/file.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Journal name},
number = {xx},
pages = {x--xx},
title = {Title},
volume = {xx},
year = {xxxx}    
}
```

Comment: I also get the error, but my PDF still gets rendered fine. All my library entries have a year and I deleted temporary files several times. So, I ignore it for now. I found out that this command always gets into the aux file: \providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Comment: I had the same problem and didn't have any BiBTeX entries without years. I was able to solve this error by changing two `\cite` commands to `\citet` or `\citep`.

Comment: remove below line in the preamble works for me
%\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Another way this error can arise is if one of your BibTeX entries has no year.

To find out which entry it is, look *earlier* in the output for a message like `Warning--empty year in ABC2019`. So check `ABC2019`.

Comment: That was indeed the case Josh. Tnx

Comment: This can also happen if a `,` is missed in the `.bib` file at the end of a line!

Comment: How come this is the accepted answer? Should it be a comment, I don't see how it solves the problem. For me it just seems like pointing a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Eduardo: It’s not just a “how to reproduce”; it explains a common cause of the problem (probably the most common cause of this error), and one with a pretty obvious fix (add a year!)

Comment: But which entry? natbib outputs an error *earlier* in processing: `Warning--empty year in ABC2019`. So check `ABC2019` (edited post to include this detail)

Comment: Any other cause? I do not have this warning. All entries have a year. I deleted the .bbl and the .aux and recompiled. I still have the error.

Comment: This is the right solution! Some of my references miss the journal or year, then this issue arises.

Answer (score 195):

When changing the bibliography style, sometimes `natbib` is upset because it can't interpret the data correctly.

In any case, after changing the argument to `\bibliographystyle` a run of LaTeX and one of BibTeX are necessary to get back in sync. Removing the `.bbl` and `.aux` files before those run is recommended, in order to avoid spurious error messages that might corrupt the `.aux` file currently being generated.

Comment: A vote here to remove *all* the temporary files- it does not seem like just the bbl+aux was enough (though I was tearing my hair out so I may not have been of entirely sound mind).  Anyway- temporary files- they'll get ya.

Comment: This fixed my problem!

Comment: Maybe one day they'll fix this issue...

Comment: Congrats on earning the "bibtex" golden badge! :-)

Comment: @Mico Almost a year after yours! ;-)

Comment: I'm glad I'm no longer the only one with this particular badge! :-)

Comment: Run BibTeX and two times LaTeX and worked for m.

Answer (score 161):

I had the same error trying to use `spmpsci.bst` in conjunction with `natbib`. While `natbib`'s default citation style is author-year, `spmpsci.bst` is numeric, so this is a strange error to get. I eventually changed the following:

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma]{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}
```

Problem went away.

Comment: The `spbasic.bst` doesn't have this problem for me, but the `spmpsci.bst` does. But if I use the `svjour3.cls` document class, I can't use natbib as you suggest, because of a clash of options. Also, doesn't setting `numbers` mean that you're no-longer using author-date?

Comment: Thanks! \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib} that helped for me.

Comment: This also worked for `eptcs.bst` (http://style.eptcs.org/)

Comment: This is a usefult solution to a different question. OP wants to output citations in author-year, not in numbers.

Comment: This solved the same error popping up with naturemag-doi.bst.  However, my inline citations (`\citet`) stopped working.

Comment: Solved my problem with `spphys.bst`. Thanks!

Comment: This solved the issue for me, thanks.

Comment: I had this problem on Overleaf with SIBGRAPI'23 template. Solved after replacing \usepackage{cite} for \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}.

Answer (score 33):

The error occurs because `natbib` cannot find year information in the `.bbl` file (or possibly, but less likely, it cannot find author information).  You can open it up yourself to see why this is the case.

The simplest reason would be that you have a `\bibitem` with the year field missing.  A trickier reason is that your bibliography style does not output year information in a way that is parsable by `natbib`.  For example, I was using `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}`, which does not play nicely with `natbib`.  I fixed the problem by using instead `\bibliographystyle{authordate1}`.  Of course, delete all temporary files, especially `.bbl` and `.aux` files, after making this change.

A final workaround is to use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` when including the package.  This outputs numbered citations instead of (author, year) citations and does not need year information.

Comment: I'm getting the same error from a bibliography in which author and year are defined for all entries, so there must be some other reasons that can trigger it.

Comment: This has worked for me

Answer (score 10):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete the `.aux` and the `.bbl` files
2. Do your changes (in the `\bibliographystyle` or in any option of `natbib`)
3. Run LaTeX
4. Run BibTeX

Comment: What changes do you mean when you say "do your changes"? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

> Another way this error can arise is if one of your BibTeX entries has no year.
>   (From Josh Porter's answer)

This is true, but due to the mismatch between `natbib` package and your `bibliographystyle` settings, instead of a bug of `natbib`, which uses its own bibliography styles (even though `natbib` supports the original bibtex styles but not completely).

`natbib` intends to offer better author-year citations. If using `natbib`, you should choose `plainnat`, `abbrvnat` or `unsrtnat`. For example,

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{articles}

\end{document}
```

Here `[round,sort]` is not necessary, which makes it look close to APA style. If you want use IEEE-like style, you could use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`.

However, if you use `apalike`, `ieeetr`, `siam`, etc., it implies you use the default bibtex styles, you should comment `natbib` package; otherwise, you would meet the problems if your bib files contain entries without author/year information.

Either way should solve your problem. This also brothers me for a long time, due to many incorrect examples in blogs.

References:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/More_Bibliographies

http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~surajit/present/bib.htm#bibstyle

Comment: useful answer, and it somehow made through to the first result in google preview

Comment: plainnat solved the problem to me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

To add to the compendium of ways this error can occur, if you are using [elsarticle.cls](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions), do not use it with options

```
    \documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
```

and the style

```
    \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case the problem was setting the cite style!!so, simply   \setcitestyle{...}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I doubt that this answers the original question. Could you please show a full solution to the problem in the question? Please remember that this is not a forum, and the Answer field is intended only for true answers to the problem.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: Actually, this suggestion is what I was looking for! Some journal document classes load `natbib` without the citation style option, and that may give rise to OP's error message even when numeric citations are being used. In those cases `\setcitestyle{number}` resolves the issue.

Comment: Setting `\setcitestyle{number}` also works for having springer styles `spmpsci` and `spbasic` output in author-year format. That's not a typo, BTW. It's the only way I found to use those styles in natbib and have author-year citations.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because of the conflict in how you define the **citation style** and the **bibliography style.** In your case, note that `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` is same as `\usepackage{natbib}`  while the 'biblographystyle' is defined as `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` meaning it is plain, basically 'numbers'.

Therefore, just change

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another not so intuitive reason for me was that I simply forgot a comma after one of the shortcodes. There was no other error and the references displayed fine, however only numerical.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if one of the BibTeX entries is missing the label (shortcode).

One possible scenario is when the bibliography is exported from e.g. EndNote and the label for the entry has not been set in EndNote. (This happened to me.)

Comment: If the entry in question doesn't have a label, how do you `\cite` it?

Comment: With the label I thought I had set, but had actually forgot to set.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use `natbib` in Beamer! Plus: possible solution

Another possibility: I have got the same errors when trying to use `natbib` in Beamer class (for presentation). The following two lines handles references properly:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bib.bib}
```

Comment: It should be `\addbibresource{bib.bib}`. In general, adding the `.bib` extension in the argument to `\bibliography` is wrong: it only works with MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for the fix; exactly, I should have mentioned that I am using MIKTex on a Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and it was over when I removed the option [authoryear]. Hope it works with you.