# How to suppress some fields in abbrv.bst

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I am using the abbrv style under the natbib package for my bibliography. Is it possible to suppress, e.g., the field "SERIES", in the output?

Here is a item in my .bib file:

```
@book{GelfandVilenkin64GF4,
      AUTHOR = {Gel'fand, I. M. and Vilenkin, N. Ya.},
      TITLE = {Generalized functions. {V}ol. 4: {A}pplications of harmonic
          analysis},
      SERIES = {Translated by Amiel Feinstein},
      PUBLISHER = {Academic Press},
      ADDRESS = {New York },
      YEAR = {1964},
      PAGES = {xiv+384},
      MRCLASS = {46.00 (46.40)},
      MRNUMBER = {0173945 (30 \#4152)},
      MRREVIEWER = {J. L. B. Cooper},
    }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The method of removing the `series` field from the `.bst` file is good; just add a definition for `series` to return an empty object: `FUNCTION{series}{""}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define a new style for that. Copy `abbrv.bst` to a new file, say `myabbrv.bst`, and put it somewhere where TeX can find it. Open it with an editor, and locate the function `format.number.series`. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Replace that with

```
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { "" }
        { output.state mid.sentence =
            { "number" }
            { "Number" }
          if$
          number tie.or.space.connect
          series empty$
            { "there's a number but no series in " cite$ * warning$ }
            { " in " * series * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

i.e., we remove the part where it writes the <series>. Then use the new style `myabbrv`.

Since you are using `natbib`, you can also use the `abbrvnat` style. There, a similar edit will help, however, there is also another option by manipulating the `\bibinfo` macro.

Comment: Thanks mafp. I followed your advice. But I get a Error message: Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations...

Comment: @Anand Well, it works here. Note that I fixed a bug in the new version of `format.number.series`. To nail down the error, please provide a complete MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: @Anand For possible reasons for your error, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54480/21591.

Comment: Dear mafp, thank you very much. It works well now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It may not be the best way. I copy the abbrv.bst to my working folder and change it to another name: abbrv_mod.bst. Then delete the entry "series" in the ENTRY part:

```
ENTRY
{ address
author
booktitle
chapter
edition
editor
howpublished
institution
journal
key
month
note
number
organization
pages
publisher
school
title
type
volume
year
}
```

Then in the tex file, use the following command:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv_mod}
```