# change the language in citations

Tags: citing, languages

I am writing my phd thesis in Albanian language. And I am encountering some issues with citations into the text. 
I would like to replace Levinsohn **and** Petrin (2003) into Levinsohn
**dhe** Petrin (2003).

do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\include{contents}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{biblio}
\end{document}   ii use as well \bibliographystyle{chicagoa}
\bibliography{referencaphd}
where one of my articles is @article{de2014firm,
 title={Firm performance in a global market},
 author={De Loecker, Jan and Goldberg, Pinelopi Koujianou},
 journal={Annu. Rev. Econ.},
 volume={6},
 number={1},
 pages={201--227},
 year={2014},
 publisher={Annual Reviews}
}

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own bibtex style to do this, but this need not be as painful as it sounds. Indeed, here is a post which does some simple customization, and we'll use that as a template here: [How to suppress some fields in abbrv.bst](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93916/how-to-suppress-some-fields-in-abbrv-bst)

You haven't specified which `bibliographystyle` you want to use. I'll work with `abbrv` here, but the same principal applies to others.

1. Make a copy of `abbrv.bst` somewhere that TeX will be able to find it (e.g. the same folder as your `.tex` file if you don't want to play with texmf trees), and name it something like `abbrv-alb.bst`. [You can find `abbrv.bst` in your tex installation, or you can download it from here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base?lang=en ]
2. Open `abbrv-alb.bst` in a plain text editor, and find the following piece of code:

---

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

3. Replace the line `{ " and " * t * }` with (in your case) `{ " dhe " * t * }`. Save the `.bst` file and close it.
4. In your `.tex` file, be sure to replace `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` with `\bibliographystyle{abbrv-alb}`, before re-compiling with latex, bibtex, latex, latex.

Comment: Postscript: A broader guide to doing this more generally can be found on this great post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles

Comment: thank you for your comment, I was trying the same thing.. is it possible that I don't have at all in my folder a chicagoa.bst file??

Comment: I only saw your comment after writing my answer. Perhaps save a copy of this file: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/chicagoa.bst

Comment: I should mention that in my folder I don't have a chicagoa.bst file... is it possible?? I have a chicagoa.tex file..in this file I made all the correction as proposed above, but now I lost all my citations and all my bibliography at the end of the document..

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in overleaf and cant change any bst file. How can do that. Maybe changing the natbib with biblatex?
[image]