# Bibliography not changing according to style

Tags: bibtex

I am having trouble formatting my bibliography to the ASA style. I would like to use the bibliography style asa.bst. I saved this .bst file within the same folder as my .tex file but do not see changes to my references. I also included this .bst file within the program files folder where other preloaded .bst files are located. My references remain in the "plain" style even with `\bibliographystyle{asa}`. Further more, when I attempt to change the bib style to "unsrt", a more common style, I still don't see changes to my references.

The code below produces a file with references not in the wanted asa style. (years should be in parentheses directly after author)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}
Blah, Blah, Blah, Science! \cite{BaGa} 

\bibliographystyle{asa}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}
```

The file named bib is as follows:

```
@book{BaGa,
title={Interactive spatial data analysis},
author={Bailey, T.C. and Gatrell, A.C.},
isbn={9780582244931},
lccn={lc95009053},
year={1995},
publisher={Longman Scientific and Technical}
}
```

The file asa.bst can be found:

http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/asa.bst

Comment: Did you run BibTeX and LaTeX again (twice) after changing the style?

Comment: Try compiling with `latexmk`. It should take care of all the things.

Comment: I had the same problem, It was ok after finding and fixing an error in my .bib file.

Answer (score 14):

Remove auxiliary files from the folder containing .tex file and .bib file. I found that deleting all the files that are created from using LaTex and BibTex fixed the problem. Leave only necessary files with in folder before running LaTex and BibTex.

[Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/package-natbib-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, I could not change the bibliography style on my file.tex output. What I did to solve it:

- Choose the `bibliographystyle` you want
- **Remove the file.bbl** (which is generated by file.bib) from your main folder
- Open and compile the file.bib (**it creates a new file.bbl**)
- Go back to your file.tex and compile

It should work if your problem is the same I had, good luck

:),
Prog

Answer (score 0):

In TexStudio, it might help to just hit F8 to remove intermediate .bbl files, and then recompile.