# Bibtex style alpha is not working

Tags: bibtex

I have made a bibliography with bibtex, however I cannot manage to get the style to change to alpha style.

I have read several answers such as [Bibliography not changing according to style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165386/bibliography-not-changing-according-to-style) but nothing is working.

I've tried recompiling with latexpdf, latexpdf, bibtex, latexpdf; I've tried deleting all my auxiliary files; and I've tried putting my bib code in different places and orders, but nothing seems to work.

My document (simplified) looks something like this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\usepackage{stmaryrd }
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}


\begin{document}




Example citations are \cite{CLS} and \cite{Herbst}. 

\bibliography{ThesisBib}{}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\end{document}
```

And my .bib file looks like this

```
    @Article{Herbst,
        Author = {Patrick {Clarke} and Josh {Guffin}},
        Title = {{On the existence of affine Landau-Ginzburg phases in gauged linear sigma models.}},
        FJournal = {{Advances in Theoretical and Mathematical Physics}},
        Journal = {{Adv. Theor. Math. Phys.}},
        ISSN = {1095-0761; 1095-0753/e},
        Volume = {19},
        Number = {4},
        Pages = {725--745},
        Year = {2015},
        Publisher = {International Press of Boston, Somerville, MA},
        Language = {English},
        DOI = {10.4310/ATMP.2015.v19.n4.a1},
        MSC2010 = {81T13 35Q56},
        Zbl = {1338.81285}
    }

@Book{CLS,
Author = {David A. {Cox} and John B. {Little} and Henry K. {Schenck}},
Title = {{Toric varieties.}},
ISBN = {978-0-8218-4819-7/hbk},
Pages = {xxiv + 841},
Year = {2011},
Publisher = {Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS)},
Language = {English},
MSC2010 = {14-01 14M25 14C17 14C15},
Zbl = {1223.14001}
}
```

The bibliography is showing up in my document; however it is showing up in plain style.

Any help fixing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I tried updating Miktex and unfortunately it didn't fix anything. Is there anything else I should be updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *"problem"* is with the `amsrefs`package. This package uses its own *bibstyles*. You can observe that if you comment `\usepackage{amsrefs}` works with `alpha` style.

When you load `amsrefs` package it uses by default the `amsrn.bst` style defined in the package.

If you still want to use the `amsrefs` package with `alpha` style you must load the package with the `alphabetic` option (or `shortalphabetic` option)

```
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}
```

or

```
\usepackage[shortalphabetic]{amsrefs}
```