# Biblatex style cannot be changed

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to change the default style of biblatex, but it is not working out. I followed the instructions given here [bibliography-not-changing-according-to-style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165386/bibliography-not-changing-according-to-style) (deleting all files and rerunning latex + biber + later), but did does not work for me. The style won't change!

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[style=numeric, language=english, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{citavi.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Test document}
I would like to cite this in style numeric. \cite{McCullagh.1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With the citvai.bib file:

```
% This file was created with Citavi 5.7.0.0

@book{McCullagh.1999,
 author = {McCullagh, Peter and Nelder, John Ashworth},
 year = {1999},
 title = {Generalized linear models},
 keywords = {Generalized linear model;Logistic regression},
 edition = {2. ed., [Nachdr.]},
 volume = {37},
 publisher = {{Chapman {\&} Hall}},
 isbn = {978-0-412-31760-6},
 shorthand = {McCullagh et al. 1999},
 language = {eng},
 location = {London},
 series = {Monographs on statistics and applied probability},
 abstract = {},
 pagetotal = {511},
 note = {Nelder, John Ashworth (VerfasserIn)},
 file = {http://gso.gbv.de/DB=2.1/PPNSET?PPN=606199969}
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

I'm using Texmaker, pdflatex to compile and `biber %` for the run of of Bib(la)tex.

Comment: Remove the `shorthand = {McCullagh et al. 1999},`. Your probably also don't want the `note = {Nelder, John Ashworth (VerfasserIn)},`. Furthermore `volume = {37},` should be `number = {37},`. Instead of `language = {eng},` you should prefer `language = {english},`. The double braces in `publisher = {{Chapman {\&} Hall}},` are not needed `publisher = {Chapman {\&} Hall},` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `shorthand` field from the entry. The `shorthand` field overrides the labels that would be generated by `biblatex`, see p. 24 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)

> [`shorthand` is] A special designation to be used by the citation style instead of the usual label. If defined, it overrides the default label.

It is a very bad idea in general to have `shorthands` resemble the author-year citation label; if you want author-year citations, use `style=authoryear` and let `biblatex` figure the label out for you - if you are unhappy with the details of the author-year label, find a way to tweak it with options and other commands instead of hard-coding it in `shorthand`. `shorthand` should be used only sparingly if you have a work that should always be referred to with a certain shorthand instead of the automatically generated labels.

Your `.bib` entry has a few other quirks as well, I would go with

```
@book{McCullagh.1999,
  author    = {McCullagh, Peter and Nelder, John Ashworth},
  year      = {1999},
  title     = {Generalized linear models},
  edition   = {2},% <- if you insist, you can go back to edition = {2. ed., [Nachdr.]},
  publisher = {Chapman \& Hall},
  location  = {London},
  series    = {Monographs on statistics and applied probability},
  number    = {37},
  isbn      = {978-0-412-31760-6},
  pagetotal = {511},
  language  = {english},
  keywords  = {Generalized linear model;Logistic regression},
  file      = {http://gso.gbv.de/DB=2.1/PPNSET?PPN=606199969}
}
```