# bibtex configuration to match Elsevier's reference requirements

Tags: bibtex

I need to configure my `bibtex` file to match Elsevier's reference [requirement](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-econometrics/0304-4076/guide-for-authors) (look for number 10). For example:

**For periodicals**

> Griffiths, W. and G. Judge, 1992, Testing and estimating location
>   vectors when the error covariance matrix is unknown. Journal of
>   Econometrics 54, 121-138.

My current `bibtex` file looks like this:

```
    @ARTICLE{Adrian2008,
  AUTHOR =       {Adrian, T., Rosenberg, J.,},
  TITLE =        {Stock Returns and Volatility: Pricing the Short-Run and Long-Run Components of Market Risk},
  JOURNAL =      {Journal of Finance},
  YEAR =         {2008},
  volume =       {63},
  pages =        {2997-3030}
}
```

And inside my main document, I refer to my `bibtex` file as:

```
\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape  %I use this to remove the italics. 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{lit3}

\endgroup
```

Following my example above, it generates this reference format:

> T. Adrian and J. Rosenberg. Stock returns and volatility: Pricing the
>   short-run and long-run components of market risk. Journal of Finance,
>   63:2997–3030, 2008.

How can I make the changes to my `bibtex` file in order to match Elsevier's requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elsevier provides some bibliography styles; the one that seems to match the recommendations is `elsarticle-harv`.

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

\cite{Adrian2008}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{plug4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that your `author` field is wrong, for the authors should be separated by `and`.

```
@article{Adrian2008,
  author  = {Adrian, T. and Rosenberg, J.},
  journal = {Journal of Finance},
  pages   = {2997-3030},
  title   = {Stock Returns and Volatility: Pricing the Short-Run and Long-Run Components of Market Risk},
  volume  = {63},
  year    = {2008},
}
```

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to use as a document class: \documentclass[english,11pt]{article} and not \documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle} and still use \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Plug4 You should try loading also `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`

Comment: Ok so if I use `\documentclass[english,11pt]{article} and \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}`, I get this error: `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations`

Comment: @Plug4 Did you run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: let me try this out ... or maybe my error is like in this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/package-natbib-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations Thanks!

Comment: Yes running the bibtex allowed me to find the error. Thanks @egreg