# Citation and bibliography customization

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib, custom-bib

I am currently writing my PhD thesis and I am  haunted by the choice of a convenient bibliography package/style/etc to meet exactly my needs of a custom list of references.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Trying citations
\citep{pollock} and \citet{pollock}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{articles}

\end{document}
```

with the following `articles.bib` file:

```
@article{pollock,
year={2050},
journal={My Journal A},
volume={27},
number={4},
title={The breakdown of single-crystal solidification},
url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/213463},
author={Pollock, T.M. and Murphy, W.H.},
pages={1000-2000},
}
```

My requirements were basically met by `natbib`'s `plainnat` or `apalike` with `authordate` setting:

- Cite using author names instead of `alpha`-style, e.g. [Bao98]
- Textual citations whenever needed, if not normal parenthical citations
- Generate a list of references that would include usual items + URL + (most importantly:) a bracketed identifier to the left of the reference, which is generated using `alpha` style in `natbib`

The last point is not possible though, which is why I tried searching  for alternate  solutions, without really finding a suitable one:

1. `dinat` solution is great but it supports german citations (produces german words inside the citation and references!)
   [image]
2. Created a custom `style.bst` using `latex makebst` tool, however the new promising style produces an error similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54480/package-natbib-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations) but cannot be fixed even after trying the suggested answers ans solutions. Maybe I should have loaded some additional packages before using it

Bottom line, is it possible or is it too much to ask from LateX ? In the meantime, I am 'procrastinating' in these links:

- [Link 1](http://www.univie.ac.at/nuhag-php/bibtex/bibstyles.pdf)
- [Link 2](http://www.mackichan.com/index.html?techtalk/632.htm~mainFrame)

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option? If you provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that would be very helpful.

Comment: I agree with @cfr. biblatex may help you solve this. And a MWE will help other people try solutions to the problem.

Comment: I ve edited the question adding a mwe. I dont mind using `biblatex`, however I still want a solution compatible with the bibiliography exported by zotero (bibTeX). I need to read more about `biblatex`

Comment: If the combination of `natbib` and `dinat.bst` deliver everything you need but for the use of German-language terms, have you considered making a copy of `dinat.bst` in which you replace the German terms with equivalent English terms?

Comment: To make full use of `biblatex`, you need to use special fields in the `.bib` file. However, `biblatex` and `biber` are fully compatible with BibTeX `.bib` files. So that shouldn't stop you from trying `biblatex`. However, as Mico says, if BibTeX does what you need, there is no reason to switch. (If it ain't broken...)

Comment: @Mico: you may be right about missing the question, i will double check. Thx though for the suggestion to modify the `dinat.bst`

Comment: @cfr  for BibTex does partly what I need to accomplish, so if `biblatex` does it easily, i am willing to invest some time reading the immense documentation.

Comment: @Mico 
1. The custom bst works, alas not giving me what i want knowing that I tried all possible authoryear options, none of them will produce a label next to the reference in the reference list.

2. I have edited the `dinat.bst` regarding the german words, it's good compromise, however I consider it perfect if:
   - I can change the author name font to normal font

Comment: @Mico 
1. The custom bst works, alas not giving me what i want knowing that I tried all possible authoryear options, none of them will produce a label next to the reference in the reference list.

2. I have edited the `dinat.bst` regarding the german words, it's good compromise, however I consider it perfect if:
   - I can change the author name font to normal font in the list
   - Modify the spacing between label and reference in the list

I tried hacking the file but its structure is more complicated than custom files generated by `makebst`, do you know if it can easily be done ? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `Natbib`

---

Considering the comments to my question, the fastest way was to hack the `dinat.bst` file changing the following:

- German to english words
- Authors name font
- Volume/number/year format
- Removed urldate field
- Removed unnecessary dashes
- Modify spacing between label and reference

Final output:
[image]

### Using `BibLateX`

---

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}% Recommended
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended
\usepackage [backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex} %style=authoryear %style=apa

\newcommand{\citep}[1]{\parencite{#1}}
\newcommand{\citet}[1]{\textcite{#1}}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{hyperref=true,backref=true,firstinits=true, isbn=false, eprint=false,
                            url=true, doi=false, sorting=nyt, minnames=1, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=2, 
                            alldates=short, punctfont=true, autopunct=false, block=none, dashed=false}

% Path to bib file (with extension)
\addbibresource{articles.bib}

% Spacing in list of references
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{15pt} %vertical spacing
\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm} %label alignment (0 for perfect align)

% Disable URL dates and language
\AtEveryBibitem{%
    \clearfield{urldate}%
    \clearfield{urlday}%
    \clearfield{urlmonth}%
    \clearfield{urlyear}%
    \clearlist{language}
}%

%Fix the comma problem after the journal name (via addcomma)
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}\addcomma\space}

%Fix number and volume format
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%Disable In prefix
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

% Define brackets instead of parenthesis
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
  \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
  \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}
\makeatother

%define label before reference in list  
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
\textbf{[\printnames[][-\value{liststop}]{labelname}~\printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}]\\}

%define full hyperlink for textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

%define full hyperlink for parencite  
 \DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

The command `\printbibliography` in the document body will print the list of references with labels.
[image]

Comment: I shall add that one reason for not adopting `biblatex` from the beginning, is because I knew that Zotero (online chrome connector) could only export in BibTeX, but actually the desktop application supports a wide array of formats including  `biblatex` (even if in the comments @cfr confirms that `biblatex` is compatible with bibTeX)

Comment: bibtex is the name of the database format.

Comment: btw: you should rename your modified file. It will get lost when the next update comes.

Comment: I meant BibTex as a backend ... As for the modifed file, it is local to my work folder so it is not affected by further updates