# Elsarticle: Getting author-year cite and bibliographystyle / Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: natbib, elsarticle, bbl

I'm using `elsarticle` for sending a preprint to Elsevier. My `.bib` has been created by Mendeley app with +300 sources. When I try to activate the option `[authoryear]` it appears:

> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

I know the correct syntax in the `.bbl` file is demanded, and yes, my `.bbl` file does not have the format:

> \bibitem **[Potter H. et all (2001)]**{potter2001)...

How can I create the `.bbl` with the **[Potter H. et all (2001)]** for every reference used without editing manually? Should I do it? Have I been missing something?

Here my code:

```
    \documentclass[review,1p,endfloat]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
    \modulolinenumbers[2]
    ...
    %Offered Elsevier's bibliography styles that I could activate:
    %% Numbered
    %\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

    %% Numbered without titles
    %\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}

    %% Harvard
    \bibliographystyle{model2-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

    %% Vancouver numbered
    %\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model3-num-names}

    %% Vancouver name/year
    %\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{model4-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

    %% APA style
    %\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}

    %% AMA style
    %\usepackage{numcompress}
    %\bibliographystyle{model6-num-names}

    %% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
    %\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

    \begin{document}
    ...
     For the purposes of this work, a physiological state will be considered 
     as the expressed metabolic response to a new stressor cite{Borowitzka2018}. 
...
    \bibliography{mybib}
    \end{document}
```

I've trying to search for an answer in this forum and others...Sorry if this could be too basic or repetitive, it is my first big document in LaTeX.

An example of ´´´.bib´´´ :

```
@article{Borowitzka2018,
author = {Borowitzka, Michael A.},
doi = {10.1007/s10811-018-1399-0},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Vladimir/Desktop/Doctorado/Publications{\_}Doctorate/Borowitzka{\_}2018{\_}The ‘ stress ' concept in microalgal biology — homeostasis , acclimation and adaptation.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0921-8971},
journal = {J. Appl. Phycol.},
keywords = {Acclimation,Adaptation,Regulation,Stress,Stress si,acclimation,adaptation,homeostasis,reactive oxygen species,regulation,stress,stress signalling},
month = {oct},
number = {5},
pages = {2815--2825},
publisher = {Journal of Applied Phycology},
title = {{The ‘stress' concept in microalgal biology—homeostasis, acclimation and adaptation}},
url = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s10811-018-1399-0},
volume = {30},
year = {2018}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Does [Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54480/24974) not answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All the references I'm using have the field year={xxx} filled.

Comment: btw, it works well for me with my sample .bib.

Comment: Your write-up is a bit confusing: On the one hand, it appears that you use BibTeX to create the formatted bibliography. On the other hand, you appear to be referring to "manually editing in thebibliography enviroment"; to me, this expression seems to indicate that the `thebibliography` environment was (is?) created by hand. Please clarify which of two possibilities applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ready! The solution was quite simple (a friend of mine told me). The reason, `.bbl`was not being made based on the bibliography style chosen. This because, indeed, **bibtex** was unable to find the styles! So, I was just not correctly routing to the `.bst` files in the correct folder.

The **elsarticle template** provides `.bst` files for creating the bibliography style. What I have done it was just create a new folder (p.e. **/bibstyles/**) next to my `.tex` with all `.bst` files inside. Then, all the codes refering to these files where set as follows:

```
%% Numbered
%\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model1-num-names}

%% Numbered without titles
%\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model1a-num-names}

%% Harvard
%\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model2-names}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,authoryear}

%% Vancouver numbered
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model3-num-names}

%% Vancouver name/year
\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model4-names}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,authoryear}

%% APA style
%\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model5-names}\biboptions{square,sort,comma,authoryear}

%% AMA style
%\usepackage{numcompress}\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/model6-num-names}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
%\bibliographystyle{bibstyles/elsarticle-num}
```

Thus, I just had to delete the old compilation files (`.bbl`,`.aux`,`.blg`,`.fff`,`.lof`,`.log`,`.lot`,`.out`,`.spl`,`.synctex.gz`,`.ttt`) and compile again. Like this, we can be sure of creating a new `.bbl`file based on the new bibliography style. (Contrary, we will be always using the previous and unwanted file).

Somehow, it was not working with the `.bbl`files directly next to `.tex` file. But inmediatly I did what I explained, it did work.

Thanks to all who submitted an answer! ;)